# Quick find and replace

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text file with two columns one with the strings to be searched and the other to be the corresponding replacement. Hence using this file A, I have to replace the contents of file B. Find the string corresponding to the first column of file A in file B and replace them by the corresponding 2nd column of file A.

How can I do it in bash

Comment: Give some input and output for your question

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{p[NR]=$1;r[NR]=$2;n=NR;next}{for(i=1;i<=n;i++)gsub(p[i],r[i])}7' A B
```

didn't test, but should work. at least you should get the idea.

Comment: It takes like ages with your method. I have 200 thousand lines in each file

Comment: @user31641 this situation definitely should be mentioned in your question. this line does a `O(MxN)`, of course is not performance optimized solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with this `Bash` sript:

```
A=path/to/A
B=path/to/B
del=" "

while read line; do
  pattern=`echo $line | cut -d "$del" -f 1`
  substitution=`echo $line | cut -d "$del" -f 2`
  sed -i "s/$pattern/$substitution/g" $B
done < $A
```

Some things to consider:

- `A` and `B` should hold the filenames for files A and B respectively
- `del` should be the single-character delimiter between columns in file A
- if your `pattern` or `substitution` columns in file A contain slashes, you need to modify the `sed` command and replace the `/` with something that can not occur in either the pattern or the substitution, e.g. `!`